# MKL sparse matrix addition fails on last entry

Tags: c++, intel-mkl

I'm trying to use the MKL routine `mkl_dcsradd` to add an upper-triangular matrix to its transpose. In this case, the upper triangular matrix stores part of the adjacency matrix of a graph, and I need the full version for implementing another algorithm.

In this simplified example, I start with a list of (11) edges, and build an upper-triangular CSR matrix from it. I have checked that this much works. However, when I try to add it to its transpose, `dcsradd` stops on the final row, saying it's run out of space. However, this shouldn't be the case. An upper triangular matrix (no zeros along the diagonal) with `n` non-zero entries, when added to its transpose, should result in a matrix with `2n` (22) non-zeros.

When I supply `dcsradd` with a maximum non-zeros of `22`, it fails, but when I supply it with `23` (an excessive value), it works correctly. Why is this?

I've simplified my code down to a minimal example demonstrating the error:

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <mkl.h>

int main()
{
    int nnz = 11;
    int numVertices = 10;

    int32_t u[] = { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 0, 1 };
    int32_t v[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 5, 8 };
    double  w[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11 };

    int fullNnz = nnz * 2;
    int dim = numVertices;

    double triData[nnz];
    int triCols[nnz];
    int triRows[dim];

    // COO to upper-triangular CSR
    int info = -1;
    int job [] = { 2, 1, 0, 0, nnz, 0 };
    mkl_dcsrcoo(job, &dim,
                triData, triCols, triRows,
                &nnz, w, u, v,
                &info);

    printf("info = %d\n", info);

    // Allocate final memory
    double data[fullNnz];
    int cols[fullNnz];
    int rows[dim];

    // B = A + A^T (to make a full adjacency matrix)
    int request = 0, sort = 0;
    double beta = 1.0;
    int WRONG_NNZ = fullNnz + 1; // What is happening here?
    mkl_dcsradd("t", &request, &sort, &dim, &dim,
                triData, triCols, triRows,
                &beta, triData, triCols, triRows,
                data, cols, rows,
                &WRONG_NNZ, &info);

    printf("info = %d\n", info);

    // Convert back to 0-based indexing (via Cilk)
    cols[:]--;
    rows[:]--;

    printf("data:");
    for (double d : data) printf("%.0f ", d);
    printf("\ncols:");
    for (int c : cols) printf("%d ", c);
    printf("\nrows:");
    for (int r : rows) printf("%d ", r);
    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

I compile with:

```
icc -O3 -std=c++11 -xHost main.cpp -o main -openmp -L/opt/intel/composerxe/mkl/lib -lmkl_intel_lp64 -lmkl_core -lmkl_intel_thread -lpthread -lm
```

When I give 22, the output is:

```
info = 0
info = 10
data:1 10 1 2 11 2 3 3 4 4 5 10 5 6 6 7 7 8 11 8 9 0 
cols:1 5 0 2 8 1 3 2 4 3 5 0 4 6 5 7 6 8 1 7 9 -1 
rows:0 2 5 7 9 11 14 16 18 21
```

But, when I give 23, the output is:

```
info = 0
info = 0
data:1 10 1 2 11 2 3 3 4 4 5 10 5 6 6 7 7 8 11 8 9 9 
cols:1 5 0 2 8 1 3 2 4 3 5 0 4 6 5 7 6 8 1 7 9 8
rows:0 2 5 7 9 11 14 16 18 21
```

Comment: I would check your compiler's documentation on whether C++ 11's range-based `for` loops work reliably on non-standard arrays.  Your `data`, `cols` and `rows` are non-standard, as you cannot declare array sizes using a runtime value in standard C++.

Comment: I'm using icc 14.0.3. If you count the entries printed by the range-based `for` loops, you'll see that it's printing the correct number of elements in all three cases. Just to be sure, though, I rewrote them as normal `for` loops, and nothing (except the syntax) changed.